# Kerberos authentication fails, "Configuration file does not specify default realm"

Tags: kerberos, freeradius

I am attempting to set up Kerberos authentication with Freeradius. At the moment when I run radtest the authentication fails and I get the following error in my logs

```
(0) Login incorrect (krb5: Failed parsing username as principal: Configuration file does not specify default realm): [user/Password123] (from client localhost port 1812)
```

In my krb5 configuration file I have specified a service principal so I am unsure why I am getting this error. Here is a snippet for context (sensitive values modified)

```
krb5 {
        #
        #  The keytab file MUST be owned by the UID/GID used by the server.
        #  The keytab file MUST be writable by the server.
        #  The keytab file MUST NOT be readable by other users on the system.
        #  The keytab file MUST exist before the server is started.
        #
        keytab = /etc/raddb/mykeytab.keytab
        service_principal = http/princ@example.com
```

Is there anything wrong with this configuration? Or am I looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to either include the realm with the principal you're logging in as, or set a default realm in krb5.conf (should be in /etc/, but it might be distro-specific).

See [here](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.17/doc/admin/conf_files/krb5_conf.html):

> **default_realm** Identifies the default Kerberos realm for the client.
>   Set its value to your Kerberos realm. If this value is not set, then a
>   realm must be specified with every Kerberos principal when invoking
>   programs such as kinit.